# Excel VBA Form - Update Labels based on cell value (Debug)

Tags: forms, vba, excel, label

I have hard times trying to update labels in a VBA form based on Worksheet values in Excel.
The methods I've tried so far:

**1st Take:**

```
Sub Update_Label_FirstTime()
Label1.Caption = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
'Whenever I call the Macro for a second time It fails and VBA freezes my form
```

**2nd Take**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
call Update_Label
End Sub

Sub Update_Label()
Label1.Caption = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Update_Label"
End Sub
' also tried Controls("Label1").Caption = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
```

These are all stored and ran from within the UserForm code. Both codes work fine on 1st load/call but **both break my form whenever I call them a second time**.
Each time I call for these updates (after the initial values are loaded) the form freezes and the VBA window in popped-up **without any code highlights or error messages**.

I have used these methods before and had no such issues.
**Any thoughts ?**

Comment: I guess the `,` is a typo in `Sheets(1),Cells(1, 1).Value` Also where are you calling this code from?

Comment: updated the post, the macros are stored and ran from within the UserForm code.

Comment: I want the labels to refresh each second (corrected the thred as there should have been UpdateLabel2) macro recalling it self. The problem is that the labels will not update on a second call the the VBA freezes.

Comment: See my answer. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: May I see your workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `Update_Label` to a standard module.

You will need to reference the form in the code.  You may also want to recalculate before getting the cell value.

```
Sub Update_Label()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    rng.Calculate
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = rng
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Update_Label"
End Sub
```